# Power SQL working with Data.tables

Tags: sql, powershell, datatable, datatables, datasource

Hi I have the following code

```
function Invoke-SQL {
    param(
        [string] $dataSource = ".\SKYPE",
        [string] $database = "LcsCDR",
        [string] $sqlCommand = "SELECT * From UsersView"
      )

    $connectionString = "Data Source=$dataSource; " +
            "Integrated Security=SSPI; " +
            "Initial Catalog=$database"

    $connection = new-object system.data.SqlClient.SQLConnection($connectionString)
    $command = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand($sqlCommand,$connection)
    $connection.Open()

    $adapter = New-Object System.Data.sqlclient.sqlDataAdapter $command
    $dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $adapter.Fill($dataSet) | Out-Null

    $connection.Close()
    $dataSet.Tables

}

$results = Invoke-SQL 

Write-Host $results.Rows.Count

foreach ($row in $results.Rows)
{
Write-Host "value is : $($row[4])"

}
```

which does what I expect in that is pulls back the content of the UserView table and loops through it out putting it to screen. All straight forward.

But I am using the column index in the output. How can I first of all list the Column headers of the table. and then be able to loop though using header rather than index numbers.

So I would like that last line to look like below, where "userid" it the column header.

```
Write-Host "value is : $($row["UserID"])"
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even have to loop!

```
$results | Select-Object "UserID"
```

Alteratives:

```
$results | Select-Object "UserID" | ForEach-Object {
    $_
}

$results | ForEach-Object {
    $_."UserID"
}
```

`$_` is somewhat akin to *"this"*

Comment: Cheers, Sadly I am still very much an amateur when it comes to scripting. What I will be doing with this table is matching to active directory user accounts based on two columns and then updating other fields in AD from other columns. Like you say I am sure there are much more efficient ways of doing this that for and if loops I still shake my in wonder at "real" scriper / programs.

Comment: @DevilWAH added a couple of methods for looping to my answer `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use my generic `Receive-SqlQuery` function that closes the `SqlConnection` and `SqlDataReader`. You can pass in a `scriptblock` to process the reader.

```
function Receive-SqlQuery
{
    Param
    (
        [string]$ConnectionString,
        [string]$SqlQuery,
        [scriptblock]$ResultProcessor
    )

    try 
    {
        $sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $ConnectionString
        $sqlConnection.Open()

        try
        {
            $sqlCommand = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($SqlQuery, $sqlConnection)
            $reader = $sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
            Invoke-Command $ResultProcessor -ArgumentList $reader
        }
        finally # cleanup reader
        {
            if ($reader)
            {
                $reader.Close()
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        $sqlConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

Usage example that access the columns using the column name:

```
 $readerCallback = {
        Param($reader)
        while ($reader.Read()) {
            Write-Host $reader['UserID']
        }    
    }

$retrieveUsers = 
@'
SELECT * From UsersView
'@

Receive-SqlQuery -ConnectionString "yourConnectionString" -SqlQuery $retrieveUsers -ResultProcessor $readerCallback
```

Comment: Why this way in preference to what I am doing? What is wrong with pulling back a data-table? I honestly have no idea personal this is beyond my limited Powershell / SQL knowledge just interested.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your solution, I just worry about closing / disposing objects thats why I prefer to pass a callback that runs in between.

Comment: See this again is where "real" coders show neat tidy well structured code compared to my ugly hacking :). Thank you for you comments and insight. :)

Answer (score 0):

Oh Sorry I see I can just use them! I spent 20 minutes trying it and blindly trying to use {} rather than []. A blind moment.

```
foreach ($row in $results.Rows)
{
Write-Host "calue is : $($row["UserID"])"

}

write-host $results.Columns
```

are the commands I was after.